# How Can I avoid Plateau?

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, training, running-training-plan, plateau

I am workingout about 6 weeks.
I don't want to hit plateau. My question is I have to change the workouts am doing or I have to increase the weight to make a change in my routine??

Example : I am currently doing benchpress (incline + decline )  and dumbell press ( incline + decline )....

now what can I do??
I have to change the workout or the weight???  or rep and sets...??

I am so skinny, weight is about 52kg and my height is 5'5". am eighteen years old.  I want to gain a lot of muscles.
  I go to the GYM 3days in a week. Sunday - Tuesday - Thursday.     I do 4-5 exercises for a single muscle group.  I try to lift hravy all the time. I do 5 sets of each exercise and try to do 5-8 reps in each sets...
  6 months ago I think I was plateaued,  and then I left the gym...   and now I joined the gym again...   So this time I want to be aware  about plateau.  So I want to change the routine in every month to make sure that I'm not doing anything bad.....

Comment: Please add more information about your workouts (days per week, exercises, weights, sets, reps), your bodyweight/height age, and nutrition/sleep.  What are you trying to achieve by working out?  Have you actually plateaued?

Comment: I am so skinny, weight is about 52kg and my height is 5'5". am eighteen years old.  I want to gain a lot of muscles.  I go to the GYM 3days in a week. Sunday - Tuesday - Thursday.     I do 4-5 exercises for a single muscle group.  I try to lift hravy all the time. I do 5 sets of each exercise and try to do 5-8 reps in each sets...        6 months ago I think I was plateaued,  and then I left the gym...   and now I joined the gym again...   So this time I want to be aware  about plateau.  So I want to change the routine in every month to make sure that I'm not doing anything bad.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation, my biggest two practical recommendations to avoid plateau/sticking are:

1. Eat enough food (and get enough good sleep) to ensure that you gain two to five pounds of bodyweight per week.
2. Don't get greedy with your weight increases.

I suggest that you read ["The First Three Questions"](http://startingstrength.com/article/the_first_three_questions) and do a [novice linear strength progression](http://startingstrength.com/article/the_novice_effect), using the low-bar barbell back squat, the overhead press, the deadlift, and the bench press.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment on your question explaining your routine and current physical state , I'd say follow these or look into these points :

1. Since you're going to the gym for about 3 days a week , I'd say increase that to about 5 days with 2 days off in a week.
2. Change your exercises, this is pretty straightforward since hitting your pecs with the same decline + incline presses will just make your body get used to that motion and hence result in no progress. Change to other pec hitting exercises ; I can't remember any but there are many available on the internet.
3. You'll hear this from everyone but eat more and eat high in protein and carbs and don't forget to add a little fat too.
4. Since I can't see any other muscle groups being trained, add some squats, deadlifts, rows .
5. With regard to the 4th point , add the compound exercises to your training, They help alot for amateurs who are looking to build their cores, add initial mass and set their form right for the future.

Comment: Great answer, welcome to fitness.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

"You don't want to hit plateau."

First of all there is nothing wrong with hitting plateau. Keep working out. Keep pushing further. Add 1 kilo or whatever weight you can. See if you can still do it.

When you finally cannot lift any further weight, try to do the same workout but in small amount of time. For example, if you completed your workout in 50 mins last time and if you manage to complete the workout in 45 mins now you are still better and stronger than before.

Try drinking water(maybe with honey) between sets, just few sips. It might help.
Remember your muscle doesn't know how much weight you are lifting, it only knows the stress it has to go through. You can still create higher stress with low weights.

If you are completely blocked out, and can't imporve any further. Reduce the normal weight you lift by half and try going 25 reps for each set. Do this for week. Then go back to normal routine, you should be able to lift heavier.

Finally, if you are just starting I would recommend to concentrate on proper form and technique rather than just hitting higher weights. Also most important thing is which we don't usually think is you can still gain muscle without lifting heavy, you just need to now how to surprise your muscles from time to time. So that you can break it can build it up with proper food.